# Why does pm2 keep holding my initial version

Tags: node.js, pm2, production-environment

I am trying to figure out how pm2 works and how I can use it in conjunction with Docker.
But I've got a weird behaviour with pm2. When I just initialize my project at the first time it seems to work - all instances are getting up and running. I can reach my the only endpoint I've got there.

But when I want to update the project (change the text that my endpoint return) I am still getting the same result (old version of the text).

I skimmed over the docs but it doesn't say anything about this freaze. So, I already tried to use `pm2 update` command, but it didn't help with the code version.

My basic setup is as the following, but if you have any other tips about any other aspect I am all ears:

ecosystem file:

```js
module.exports = {
    apps: [{
        name: "api",
        script: "./dist/server.js",
        instances: 0,
        merge_logs: true,
        max_restarts: 20,
        max_memory_restart: "200M",
        watch: true,
        env: {
            "NODE_ENV": "development",
        }
    }]
}
```

the way I am lauching it:

```
"scripts": {
    "pm2": "pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --no-daemon",
    "dev": "tsc-watch --noClear --onSuccess \"node ./dist/server.js\"",
    "start": "tsc && node ./dist/server.js"
},
```

as I thought `PM2` is not making any images like Docker does. It just takes what it can find in the directory and launch the script, but now It seems like there is some either image building or caching.

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake and the issue was - I didn't recompile the code.

I just forgot I am not in a watch mode in `Typescript`